# Changing CSS inner Background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a little piece of code

```
"spots": [{
    "id": "rect-5115",
    "type": "rect",
    "x": 8,
    "y": 52.7,
    "width": 34.6,
    "height": 16.7,
    "default_style": {
        "border_radius": 10,
        "background_color": "#c0c0c0",
        "background_opacity": 0.18943843984962405
    },
    "mouseover_style": {
        "border_radius": 10,
        "background_color": "#c0c0c0",
        "background_opacity": 0.18943843984962405,
        "fill": "#000000"
    },
    "tooltip_style": {
        "auto_width": 1
```

I tried to change the background color using below code for **default_style**. but this is not working, in fact the ID: "rect-5115" consist of 2 background_color in the following tags as listed in the code above:

1. default_style
2. mouseover_style

i need to change the background color for the **default_style** rather than the **mouseover_style** when the **Button_on** is clicked.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Button_on').click(function(){
            $('#rect-5115').css('background_color','#ff0000');
        });
    });
```

I tried several ways to do so but its not working, can you please guide me through the proper channel.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use hyphen or camelCase in css selectors for .css() method:

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css(
>   "backgroundColor" ). This means mixed case has a special meaning,
>   .css( "WiDtH" ) won't do the same as .css( "width" ), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$('#rect-5115').css('background-color','#ff0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `.css()` rule, it's `background-color` with a hyphen instead of an underscore.

For the hover parts, apply styles to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Button_on').click(function(){
        $('#rect-5115').css('background-color','#FF0000');
 $("#rect-5115").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css("background", "#00FF00");
 }).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).css("background", "#FF0000");
 });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Button_on">button</button>
<div id="rect-5115">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Thanks a lot for your inputs.

infact if you see the code: there is an underscore in the background_color, this is quite puzzling.

the **background_color** form part of the **default_style**. this is what i wanted to change using JS.

```
"spots": [{
    "id": "rect-5115",
    "type": "rect",
    "x": 8,
    "y": 52.7,
    "width": 34.6,
    "height": 16.7,
    "**default_style**": {
        "border_radius": 10,
        **"background_color": "#c0c0c0",**
        "background_opacity": 0.18943843984962405
    },
    "mouseover_style": {
        "border_radius": 10,
        **"background_color": "#c0c0c0",**
        "background_opacity": 0.18943843984962405,
        "fill": "#000000"
    },
    "tooltip_style": {
        "auto_width": 1
```